# uncaught at rootSaga at rootSaga at watchFecthUsers at takeLatest at fetUsers ReferenceError: error is not defined

Tags: syntax-error, react-native

user.js get user

```
 import { FETCTH_FAIL, FETCTH_SUCCES, FETCTH_USER } from "../action/actionTypes";
    import { put, takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";
    import Api from "./App";
    
    function* fetUsers() {
      try {
        const users = yield Api.getUsers();
        yield put({ type: FETCTH_SUCCES, users: users });
      } catch (err) {
        yield put({ type: FETCTH_FAIL, error });
      }
    }
    
    export function* watchFecthUsers() {
      yield takeLatest(FETCTH_USER, fetUsers);
    }
```

rootSaga.js rootSaga

```
import { call, all } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { watchFecthUsers } from "./users";

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield call(watchFecthUsers);
}
```

actionTypes.js action

```
export const FETCTH_USER = 'fetchuser';
export const FETCTH_SUCCES = 'fetchsucces';
export const FETCTH_FAIL = 'fetchfail';
```

I get Error mentioned below

> D:\android_ios\sagaredux\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:71 uncaught at rootSaga at rootSaga
>
> at watchFecthUsers
>
> at takeLatest
>
> at fetUsers
>
> ReferenceError: error is not defined

Comment: why nobody help me T_T  ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very late to answer but just for the sake of clarity on this error
**yield put({ type: FETCTH_FAIL, error });**
In the above line 'error' is not defined hence the error occurs.
You can change this line to something like below:
**yield put({ type: FETCTH_FAIL, error:err });** where 'err' is the catch block's variable name.